# Is there any solution to change the source IP from outgoing WAN A to receiving WAN B?

Tags: routing, ip, nat, gateway

I am configuring a office router for crossing the GFW in China.

I want to use WAN A(actually a low bandwidth VPN tunnel) only to send package to target servers (YouTube for example). And change the source IP to WAN B(normal internet with good bandwidth).

Then the WAN B can received the data from servers properly.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: It is possible to do SNAT on the packets leaving WAN A to set the source IP to that of WAN B's. But the ISP of WAN A may or may not allow packets with forges source addresses to leave its network.

Comment: This is basically a NAT, but with the issue that WAN B would receive ACKs without issuing SYN first. That would require further modification of routers/firewalls along the route, as well as custom application on WAN B side

Comment: I think the difficult part is spoofing the source IP address. If ISP allowing this, it could cause attacking on the forged source IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've been missing something all these years, no it isn't possible.

What you are wanting is for your office computers to initiate a request to Youtube across WAN A's tunnel and then receive that request back through WAN B (their normal internet connection).

TCP/IP simply doesn't work that way.  You're not going to be able to spoof/NAT the source IP and have it actually route out WAN A's ISP, they wouldn't route it.  Even if you could, the return packets back to WAN B wouldn't know where to go once they got to WAN B's router since there would be no existing TCP/UDP session in its session table, so it wouldn't have any idea where to send the packets "downstream" to the original requesting office computer.

You can either hope to use a proxy and not get in trouble with the Chinese government, or you can use WAN A for the entire TCP/UDP session.

Comment: So if we can make two modifications:1)config the WAN A's router to allow source IP spoof;2)program the WAN B gateway to have SYN status on session table. it should work?

Comment: You won't be able to do either one...